Trackball Behaviour With Modal Operator
I need to create a trackball like behaviour for a modal operator.
Is there a possibility to implement this into the functionality by moving the mouse?
I just need to know how the math works when converting the x and y movement from the mouse to the view bound xyz rotation conversion.
This is what I got for now
#n = AXIS OF ROTATION
#a = DEGREES TO ROTATE
#v = VECTOR TO ROTATE
def axesAngleRot(n, a, v):
    return v * math.cos(a) + (v.dot(n))*n*(1-math.cos(a)) + (n.cross(v)*math.sin(a))

def getViewMatrix():
    area = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"][0]
    with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
        view3d = bpy.context.space_data
        view_matrix = view3d.region_3d.view_matrix

    right_viewMatrix = mathutils.Vector((view_matrix[0][0], view_matrix[1][0], view_matrix[2][0]))
    up_viewMatrix = mathutils.Vector((view_matrix[0][1], view_matrix[1][1], view_matrix[2][1]))
    forward_viewMatrix = mathutils.Vector((view_matrix[0][2], view_matrix[1][2], view_matrix[2][2]))


    return [right_viewMatrix, up_viewMatrix, forward_viewMatrix]

